# Rewrite for loop as while loop

Tags: python

I am learning python.

For the code below, how to convert for loop to while loop in an efficient way?

```
import pandas as pd 

transactions01 = [] 

file=open('raw-data1.txt','w')
file.write('HotDogs,Buns\nHotDogs,Buns\nHotDogs,Coke,Chips\nChips,Coke\nChips,Ketchup\nHotDogs,Coke,Chips\n')
file.close()

file=open('raw-data1.txt','r')

lines = file.readlines()  

for line in lines:
    items = line[:-1].split(',')      
    has_item = {}
    for item in items:
        has_item[item] = 1
    transactions01.append(has_item)**
        
file.close()

data = pd.DataFrame(transactions01)

data.fillna(0, inplace = True)
data
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want a `while` loop... there's no obvious reason as to why it'd make sense here...

Answer (score 1):

Code :

```
i = 0
while i<len(lines):
    items = lines[i][:-1].split(',')
    has_item = {}
    j = 0
    while j<len(items):
        has_item[items[j]]=1
        j+=1
    transactions01.append(has_item)
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could just take your, use the csv module to parse the file as you've got an inconsistent number of rows per column, then turn it into a dataframe, use `pd.get_dummies` to get 0/1's per item present, then aggregate back to a row level to product your final output, eg:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

with open('raw-data1.txt') as fin:
    df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(csv.reader(fin)).stack()).groupby(level=0).max()
```

Will give you a `df` of:

```
   Buns  Chips  Coke  HotDogs  Ketchup
0     1      0     0        1        0
1     1      0     0        1        0
2     0      1     1        1        0
3     0      1     1        0        0
4     0      1     0        0        1
5     0      1     1        1        0
```

.. which you can then write back out as CSV if required.